# Background During Activity Transitions

Tags: java, android, background, themes

spent a little time googling this and couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

My app has it's own theme with a drawable that is used for the background of my entire app. When transitioning between activities though, the home screen background can be seen for a split second.

How do I prevent the home screen's background from being seen? It's almost like the current activity goes away just before the new one is drawn on the screen, and so I'm left looking at the home screen wallpaper for a split second.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you starting the new `Activity`? Are you calling `finish()` in the old `Activity`?

Comment: I'm just creating an Intent for most of my activities and then calling startActivity(intent). I am not calling finish() in the old activity. Should that be called right after startActivity()? What is the reason/benefit of calling finish()?

Comment: finish() terminates the old activity. Calling it will not help you. I don't hunk it's possible to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I was using the Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen theme, which has an attribute that makes the user's wallpaper show as the background of their app. I then created a background for my app that was very, very similar to the background on my phone, so I didn't notice it until I changed the background on my phone. anyway, I created my own style based off of the Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen, and changed the android:windowShowWallpaper value from true to false.

Comment: Why use the Wallpaper variant if you are not going to show the wallpaper? `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` seems like a better choice here.